# How do i properly install livewires?

Tags: python, package, livewires

I'm teaching myself python with a text book I have, and i'm nearing the end of of the book. But it wants me to install pygame and livewires for the lesson's project. After awhile i installed pygame and it's working well, but i can't get livewires to work properly, I installed it by typing "pip install LiveWires" into the command prompt, but when i try to import the module games in the python shell, i get this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module> from livewires import games File "C:\Users\young\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\livewires\__init__.py", line 32, in <module> from beginners import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beginners'`

Is there a different way I can install the package? And is there a solution to this problem? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module error for 'beginners' in livewires MacOS - beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67775123/module-error-for-beginners-in-livewires-macos-beginner)

Answer (score 0):

You can install it with dependent modules. Also probably you will need updated version superwires instead of livewires. Livewires worked with errors for me, but superwires just fine. For Linux:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo apt install python3-pygame
pip3 install livewires
pip3 install superwires
```