# Module error for 'beginners' in livewires MacOS - beginner

Tags: python, module, modulenotfounderror, livewires

I am a beginner at python and is following a book named 'Python programmming for the absolute beginner' and has issues on importing livewires.

When I write `from livewires import games` it pops up with the error:

```
line 1, in <module>
from livewires import games
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/livewires/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
from beginners import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beginners'
```

I am not sure how to deal with this as i've researched this and I've not cam back with a solution.

The way I installed livewires (I have already installed pygame)

```
pip install livewires
```

and

```
pip install superwires
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65585994 as reference

Comment: @汪心禾WangXinHe the answers there are for Linux not mac OS

Comment: I found that https://stackoverflow.com/a/66071279/11073264 is incorrect, my answer might help you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [LiveWires](https://pypi.org/project/LiveWires/) only supports Python 2. You may use [SuperWires](https://pypi.org/project/SuperWires/) instead of LiveWires:

```sh
pip3 install superwires
```

```py
from superwires import games  # Just replace `livewires` with `superwires`
```

###### References

- https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2011-November/086552.html
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/949054/livewires-module-isnt-working
- [Installing livewires for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123018/installing-livewires-for-python)